# Kernel density estimator for sum of marginals

Tags: probability, density-function, kernel-smoothing

Imagine that there are two random variables $X$ and $Y$ with corresponding density functions and a joint density given by $f(x,y)$. The expected value of the kernel density estimator of the joint is given by

$$
E[\hat{f}(x,y)] = h^{-2} \int K\left(\frac{x-X}{h},\frac{y-Y}{h}\right)f(X,Y)dXdY \approx f(x,y)
$$
where $K(.)$ is the kernel function and $h$ is the bandwidth parameter. Imagine the following setup. Suppose there is a function $p(X,Y) = X + Y$ which adds up the marginals. What would be the expected kernel density estimate of a point over this function? Can I write the following for a given point $z$?

$$
E[\hat{f_p}(z)] = h^{-1} \int K\left(\frac{z-p(X,Y)}{h}\right)f(X,Y)dXdY
$$

Do you know if this can be expressed in terms of $f(x,y)$, $f(x)$ and $f(y)$ or corresponding estimates?